# Module not found [protonego-impl/alpn-1.8.0_45] when running Jetty from IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty

I've been trying to run Jetty on IntelliJ using the build-in Jetty server support, and with the latest Jetty version (9.2.10.v20150310).
However, when I try to deploy my war, it fails and throws the exception:

> WARNING: Module not found [protonego-impl/alpn-1.8.0_45]
>   WARNING: ** Unable to continue, required dependency missing. [protonego-impl/alpn-1.8.0_45]
>   WARNING: ** As configured, Jetty is unable to start due to a missing enabled module dependency.
>   WARNING: ** This may be due to a transitive dependency akin to spdy on npn, which resolves based on the JDK in use.
>   Missing referenced dependency: protonego-impl/alpn-1.8.0_45

This module version indeed does not exist in the jetty folder (In the protonego-impl folder, the versions end at alpn-1.8.0_31), And I can't seem to find it anywhere to download.. Has anyone come across this exception?

Comment: Which JDK are you using to run Jetty on IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release of Jetty 9.2.10 predates the release of Java 1.8.0u45

In order to support HTTP/2 (and SPDY), there is a need for ALPN support at the Java Classlib level.  This is accomplished with a `-Xbootclasspath` jar that Jetty produces that supplements SSL within Java itself to support ALPN.

That means Jetty maintains a set of modifications for Java's SSL, which means Jetty also has to maintain a mapping of Java version to ALPN lib versions.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions

From there you can see that for Java 1.8u45 can use ALPN lib 8.1.3.v20150130 (the same version of ALPN that Java 1.8u31 uses)

Obviously Jetty 9.2.10 cannot ship with this mapping as that would have required a time machine to accomplish.

**How to correct this on your machine:**

To start with, all of these changes are to your instance configuration in your `${jetty.base}` directory (You do have a ${jetty.base} directory and are not modifying `${jetty.home}`, right?)

- Make a `${jetty.base}/modules/protonego-impl` directory
- Copy (and rename) `${jetty.home}/modules/protonego-impl/alpn-1.8.0_31.mod` to `${jetty.base}/modules/protonego-impl/alpn-1.8.0_45.mod`
- Start your Jetty instance from your `${jetty.base}` directory.

You are done your instance is now capable of running ALPN lib 8.1.3.v20150130 with Java 1.8u45

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using a JDK version which is not fully supported by the Jetty version you have.
In fact if you look at [this Jetty commit](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-commit/msg10811.html) dated 15 April 2015, it states

> Updated ALPN and NPN versions for JDK 7u79, 7u80 and 8u45.

and it will likely be inserted in version 9.2.11.
So my advice would be use JDK version 1.7.x as reported in [official documentation support tables](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.10.v20150310/what-jetty-version.html#d0e162) or Java 1.8.0u31.